# Getting exception when adding pin to Mapsui (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms, mapsui

I am trying to add a pin to my Xamarin Forms Mapsui control.

Here is my Xaml

```
<mapsui:MapView x:Name="selectMapControl"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        BackgroundColor="Gray" />
```

Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            var map = new Map
            {
                CRS = "EPSG:3857",
                Transformation = new MinimalTransformation()
            };

            var tileLayer = OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer();

            map.Layers.Add(tileLayer);
            map.Widgets.Add(new Mapsui.Widgets.ScaleBar.ScaleBarWidget(map) { TextAlignment = Mapsui.Widgets.Alignment.Center, HorizontalAlignment = Mapsui.Widgets.HorizontalAlignment.Left, VerticalAlignment = Mapsui.Widgets.VerticalAlignment.Bottom });

            selectMapControl.Map = map;

            double lat = 36.9628066;
            double lng = -122.0194722;

            var myPosition = new Position(lat, lng);
            var myPin = new Pin(selectMapControl) //Exception here
            {
               Position = myPosition,
               Type = PinType.Pin,
               Label = "Zero point",
               Address = "Zero point",
            };
            selectMapControl.Pins.Add(myPin);
}
```

I receive an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" exception on the line *var myPin = new Pin(selectMapControl)...*

If my lat and lng are both set to 0 then it works

Here is the stack trace in the exception:

```
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00114] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:510   
    at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x00173] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:446       
    at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x0004d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:374   
    at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:349   
    at Mapsui.UI.Forms.Pin.set_Position (Mapsui.UI.Forms.Position value) [0x00000] in <5cc65edf513349cdba641e049bbf0143>:0   
    at eLunaApp.Views.RestaurantMapPage.OnAppearing () [0x0008d] in C:\x\elunaapp\eLunaApp\PageRestaurantMap\RestaurantMapPage.xaml.cs:82   
    at Xamarin.Forms.Page.SendAppearing () [0x00045] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:452   
    at Xamarin.Forms.ShellContent.SendPageAppearing (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x0003b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Shell\ShellContent.cs:127   
    at Xamarin.Forms.ShellContent.SendAppearing () [0x00019] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Shell\ShellContent.cs:108   
    at Xamarin.Forms.ShellContent.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.Element child) [0x00021] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Shell\ShellContent.cs:138   
    at Xamarin.Forms.ShellContent.set_ContentCache (Xamarin.Forms.Page value) [0x0003b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Shell\ShellContent.cs:182   
    at Xamarin.Forms.ShellContent.Xamarin.Forms.IShellContentController.GetOrCreateContent () [0x0003c] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Shell\ShellContent.cs:68   
    at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ShellSectionRenderer.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x000f2] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ShellSectionRenderer.cs:166   
    at AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_inflater, System.IntPtr native_container, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00021] in D:\a\1\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release\monoandroid90\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:1950   
    at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.50(intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)  
    at Mapsui.UI.Forms.Pin.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x001df] in <5cc65edf513349cdba641e049bbf0143>:0   
    at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00114] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:510  
    at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x00173] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:446  
    at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x0004d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:374  
    at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:349   
    at Mapsui.UI.Forms.Pin.set_Position (Mapsui.UI.Forms.Position value) [0x00000] in <5cc65edf513349cdba641e049bbf0143>:0   
    at eLunaApp.Views.RestaurantMapPage.OnAppearing () [0x0008d] in C:\x\elunaapp\eLunaApp\PageRestaurantMap\RestaurantMapPage.xaml.cs:82  
    at Xamarin.Forms.Page.SendAppearing () [0x00045] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:452  
    at Xamarin.Forms.ShellContent.SendPageAppearing (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x0003b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Shell\ShellContent.cs:127   
    at Xamarin.Forms.ShellContent.SendAppearing () [0x00019] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Shell\ShellContent.cs:108   
    at Xamarin.Forms.ShellContent.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.Element child) [0x00021] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Shell\ShellContent.cs:138   
    at Xamarin.Forms.ShellContent.set_ContentCache (Xamarin.Forms.Page value) [0x0003b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Shell\ShellContent.cs:182   
    at Xamarin.Forms.ShellContent.Xamarin.Forms.IShellContentController.GetOrCreateContent () [0x0003c] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Shell\ShellContent.cs:68   
    at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ShellSectionRenderer.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x000f2] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ShellSectionRenderer.cs:166   
    at AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_inflater, System.IntPtr native_container, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00021] in D:\a\1\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release\monoandroid90\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:1950   
    at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.50(intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Comment: is `Pins` null?  You should check and initialize it first.  And why are you passing a new instance of `MapView` to the `Pin` constructor?

Comment: Okay. I updated the code. I pass selectMapControl instead of a new instance of *MapView* and moved the *New Position* and *New Pin* to separate lines. The exception is on the *New Pin* line so it is not related to if Pins is null I guess

Comment: what happens if you use the default constructor for Pin?

Comment: If you mean *var myPin = new Pin();* then that works but later I get a 'var myPin = new Pin();' exception

Comment: I suggest you open an issue with MapsUI

Comment: Okay. I appreciate your time.

Comment: This is great on .Net Maui, placing a pin worked a treat. Just changed Position = new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude), where locations comes from the IGeolocation interface. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRXiiy800XY&list=PLfbOp004UaYVt1En4WW3pVuM-vm66OqZe&index=9  I've only spent three days trying to do that! :)