# Adding pins based on addresses for Mapsui

Tags: xamarin.forms, mapsui

Is it possible to add a pin on the map based on an address only, without providing specific coordinates?

If yes, how and what information is needed (e.g. is postal code necessary)?

Comment: No you have to geocode the addresses first

Comment: No luck. Tried to add a position for the Pin and I'm getting this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66294770/getting-exception-when-adding-pin-to-mapsui-xamarin-forms
Is there any solution or any alternative to Mapsui for OpenStreetMap?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You can check the [resource code of the Pin class in the Mapsui](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/blob/master/Mapsui.UI.Forms/Objects/Pin.cs#L43). The Location property has the [Position class](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/blob/master/Mapsui.UI.Forms/Objects/Position.cs)'s default value.

So even you don't declare the Location property. It will also use the default value. So if you want to add the pin based on the addresses. You may need to custom the Pin class by yourself.

In addition, the address peroperty of the Pin class is type of string. You need to convert the string to a exactly position.

Comment: It would also make sense for the pin to get positioned only by an address. When searching the maps an address is sufficient for returning a result.

Comment: Tried to add a position for the Pin and I'm getting this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66294770/getting-exception-when-adding-pin-to-mapsui-xamarin-forms
Is there any solution?

Comment: Just as the comment in this thread said, you can open a new issue with the mapsui.

Comment: The thread is 2 years old. Has the issue ever got resolved?

By the way, do I need to transform the coordinates I get from [Geocoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geocoding?tabs=android) from EPSG: 4326 to EPSG 3857, before passing them to the `Pin`'s  `Position` property or not??

Comment: Did you mean when you used `var pin = new Pin(mapview){ Position = new Mapsui.UI.Forms.Position(vlaue1, value2) }` will throw an error?

Comment: Yes. If I remove the `Position = new Mapsui.UI.Forms.Position(vlaue1, value2)` line from the new Pin and I leave all the other properties, e.g. Address, the error goes away.

Comment: Did you check [the official sample code](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui/blob/152843fcf5ed60147523c98e3dedf39aff46f54d/Samples/Mapsui.Samples.Forms/Mapsui.Samples.Forms.Shared/PinSample.cs#L40)? @Costas

Comment: What about it? I see that they assign a Pin at the point clicked on the map: `Position = mapClickedArgs.Point`